# SwiftUI: Alternatives to using ListView?

Tags: swiftui

I want to have a scrollable list that when each row is tapped, it takes you to a different view.  Inside each row, I want to have a heart button that when tapped overrides the navigation behavior and just toggles a heart fill/unfill.
As an alternative to do this, would it make sense to use a ScrollView inside a NavigationView and then have each list item be a `VStack`?

Pseudocode hierarchy:

```
NavigationView {
   ScrollView {
      VStack {
         // Button       
      }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way ( or more preferred way) to accomplish this?

Comment: Yep, use a [`ForEach`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach) inside a container `VStack`. Then inside the `ForEach`, add your `VStack` that contains a button.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LazyVStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvstack)

```
let items = ["A","B"]

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```